# Link corners (draw hypotenuse) of rectangle using pen tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I can draw rectangle using pen tool. Is there any way to draw a hypotenuse while drawing rectangle without manually doing it using line tool?

[image: draw hypotenuse]

Comment: I guess you must be deleting the rectangle's corner point while attempting this? If so, first deselect the rectangle, then draw your hypotenuse. That is, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without deselecting? Cause, deselecting and then drawing will make 2 different shapes. I want a single shape.

Comment: You could make 2 separate shapes and then merge them? that would be the easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

Without completely understanding why you want to do this, here is how you might do it. (Using Adobe Illustrator.)

1. As you have already been doing, draw three sides of the rectangle with the pen tool
2. When drawing the fourth side, instead of closing the rectangle by clicking on the first anchor point, click *near* the first point.
3. Then, continuing the path, make the hypotenuse by clicking *near* the diagonally opposite point. It might look like this:
   [image]
4. Press <kbd>A</kbd> key to switch to the direct selection tool, or hold `Command/Ctrl` (Mac/PC) and reposition the last two points over the top of the points they are near. Result:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

**No**

There is no automated way to draw the a corner to corner path in Illustrator. It has to be done manually.

It is fairly easy to use automated features such as `Object > Path > Average` to ensure the disecting path aligns with corners properly, after its drawn.